# Protecting against web service content mapping - WebForms PageMethods

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, webforms, pagemethods

I am working on a project that is a .NET WebForms solution that contains many PageMethod's to act like an MVC hybrid.

We have a registration service in our product that upon typing your username, will call a service to immediately check if the username has already been chosen (without calling a post-back).

What would be the most appropriate way of preventing someone from mapping out the entire username database by brute-forcing requests for true/false answers on if a string exists as a username.

The best method I can currently think of is throttling requests based on session, which would not completely stop the problem, but like encryption, make the time-cost to effectively succeed not worth it for the intruders.

In my head I was thinking along the lines of:

```
Public Function SomeFunction() as String
Dim throttle As Throttle = New Throttle()
        If Not HttpContext.Current.Session("IsUsernameExistsThrottle") Is Nothing Then
            throttle = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Session("IsUsernameExistsThrottle"), Throttle)
            If Not throttle.SetExpiry Is Nothing Then
                If throttle.SetExpiry > DateTime.Now Then
                    Throw New Exception("Please wait 1 minute before accessing this functionality again.")
                Else
                    throttle.SetExpiry = Nothing
                End If
            Else
                throttle.RequestCount += 1
                If throttle.RequestCount >= 10 Then
                    throttle.SetExpiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            throttle.SetExpiry = Nothing
            throttle.RequestCount = 1
        End If
        HttpContext.Current.Session("IsUsernameExistsThrottle") = throttle
        Return SomeValue
End Function

    Public Class Throttle
        Public RequestCount As Integer
        Public SetExpiry As DateTime?
    End Class
```

What this function would do is allow the first 10 requests for free, and then throttle every request afterwards to 1 per minute.

Any thoughts or suggestions, or recommendations for best practice?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please clarify why attacker will use the same session? If you check out existing SO questions on scraping you'll see that it is not exactly easiest way to make requests...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The built in mechanism of the system will deny the user access to any functionality unless a T&C's page has been accepted first bound to a session. Essentially creating a new session per request will result in failure due to not accepting terms. Could you explain what you mean by it is not the easiest way to make requests?

Comment: Did you notice that you completely skipped that part in your question? How one would guess that session is required?  (I don't think adding details would actually help your questions as it is a bit too broad / opinion based... Solving such problem properly requires one to have very detailed threat model and good understanding of costs associated with each treat. It is unlikely that you can provide enough details for one to give you concrete assessment. Even basic `Task.Delay(1000)` may be enough depending on costs).

Comment: You may want to attack your server yourself to see what you'll use - at least you'll have some basic idea what is involved (couple GET/POST requests is usually enough for most sites)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you, and I completely understand that it is quite broad. The current threat is non-existant and more just a problem I found in my own penetration testing of the software. The risk in my eyes is quite low, at the end of the day an attacker is probably more interested in knowing if specific usernames exist which they can do so regardless. I am just making the idea of mapping out the whole username database too high of cost to the attacker. My post was more to see if anyone said hell no to my idea, or had a very quick, efficient alternative that may have been built in etc.